# No tasks available when executing JUnit runner class

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit, test-runner

I am trying to run Cucumber feature files in IntelliJ.

Cucumber Options is pointing to the right folder, but I get the "No tasks available" notification when trying to execute the JUnit runner class.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.7.1'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.44.0'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.7.1'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
    compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '4.7.1'
    compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '4.7.1'
    compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '4.7.1'
    compile group: 'net.masterthought', name: 'cucumber-reporting', version: '3.20.0'
    compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'gherkin', version: '5.1.0'
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-picocontainer', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '3.6.0'
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to share project example for investigation?

Comment: Not all of the project. What do you need?

Comment: Could you create small project example demonstrating the issue, so dependencies/classpath/etc. could be checked?

Comment: @MateMrše Are you able to run the tests outside of IntelliJ, using the command line?

Comment: Please start with removing the 'cucumber-core' dependency (it is included in `cucumber-java`) and updating the `cucumber-picocontainer` to:` 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-picocontainer', version: '4.7.1'` (making sure to use the same cucumber version for all your cucumber dependencies.

Comment: Reimporting gradle projects fixed this for me

Comment: @Rob I don't think this applies to this screenshot. I wanted to show the message that pops up. Besides, everything of interest already is typed into the question.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Ok, none of the proposed solutions worked, but I finally figured it out.

Went to `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle` and changed `Run tests using:` from `Gradle (Default)` to `IntelliJ IDEA`.

[image]

Note: found the solution [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207307465-IntelliJ-can-t-run-unit-tests-in-hierarchical-gradle-project-).

Comment: What if I don't have a gradle option there? Only maven

Comment: I'm not sure about Maven, but I imagine it should be similar to this, just select Maven as build tool and then see what are the available options.

Comment: this did not work for me. reimporting gradle project from gradle view worked

Answer (score 50):

When I had this problem ("No tasks available" message when trying to run a test), what worked for me was to simply re-import the project from the Gradle view.

`Right-click` on project in Gradle view and select `Reimport Gradle Project`.

Comment: Note: 'Reimport All Gradle Projects' didn't work for me, at least in the version I tested it in. That's why I wrote instructions for re-importing the individual project.

Comment: This worked for me, but it appears to be named `Reload Gradle Project` now.

Answer (score 16):

I was facing the same issue.
When using gradle make sure your project structure is correct.
Your tests should be in **src>test>java**

This resolved the issue for me.

[image: Java Test Structure]

Comment: Thanks, actually this solved the problem that took me hours strugggling.

Comment: it really help me a lot, thanks

Answer (score 8):

"No tasks available" – I got this message when trying to run Spock test.

The reason was I did not have gradle plugins configured properly:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'groovy' // this one is also necessary
}
```

Make sure you have 'groovy' plugin enabled, then re-import your project.

Comment: That was it, my Groovy tests are running, using only IntelliJ. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. When I used the full package name in glue it worked, this is mine:

```
    ...
    features = "src/test/resources/features",
    glue = {"test.java.stepdefinitions"},
    ...
```

Comment: where to make this change?

Comment: In @CucmberOptions. See question on top of the page

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar issue, In my case, it was because I forget to use the "public" access modifier while defining test class, and apparent with Junit 4, all test classes should be public.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30128549)

Comment: @Rana BS, I ran into the exact same issue, and this solved it. Actually, I came to add the solution in case it didn't exist yet (funny how the same tests do run on other platforms).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I was trying to run the JUnit tests in my Gradle project. the solution worked in my case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Android Studio, open the Gradle panel and right click on your project name, then click on Reload Gradle Project

[image]