# Test Framework quit unexpectedly - Cucumber Test - Intellij Via Feature file

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber

When i run my cucucumber Test via Runner class, they run fine but when Run via Feature file i get this error in Intellij Idea 2020.3

**Test framework Quit unexpectedly**

[image]

Below is a **successful** run via Runner class

[image]

please let me know where i am going wrong when running via feature file

Also attaching the configuration after looking at existing answers

[image]

here is the code
**https://github.com/gauravkhuraana/RestAssured_ToolsQA**

Comment: Thanks for replying , just did the checkin https://github.com/gauravkhuraana/RestAssured_ToolsQA

Comment: See if changing executor to IntelliJ does anything> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57908805/no-tasks-available-when-executing-junit-runner-class

Comment: @MateMrše i am using maven,, so dont find the option which is there for Gradle

Comment: Oh, I see. But is there a way to set IntelliJ as test executor?

Comment: Works fine on my side with default run configuration (created by pressing on double play button). Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: @MateMrše i tried the link which you shared,, there was some option to select intellij for gradle.. but i am using maven

Comment: @y.bedrov could you let me know whats the double play button.. if you can share screenshot .... https://easyupload.io/xd7m4u here i have uploaded the log file

Comment: I meant two green triangles on left gutter on the first line of feature file. It creates default temporarily configuration.

Comment: thanks @y.bedrov same problem even running from that button

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with run configuraion created that way?

Comment: @y.bedrov https://imgur.com/a/yCCN6yW here is the link when run with the play button

Comment: Please try to set "Main class" to io.cucumber.core.cli.Main

Comment: now this is the error @y.bedrov https://imgur.com/a/d3DjA2k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @y.bedrov for the guidance

Adding the below in **Main Class** for configuration

```
io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
```

and adding just the folder name (not full path) for **StepDefintion** in configuration has fixed this problem

[image]

Comment: Got the same issue, but on the template (I had to fill all properties on the template).