# IDE shows no tasks available while running a simple test class in android studio

Tags: android, testing, junit

created a simple test class to check the statistics of a TO-DO List app.
refer - https://learn.udacity.com/courses/ud940/lessons/d6e700ab-b5d9-4b7b-8bab-64ab79c88f87/concepts/e4e37d5c-2b18-403d-83d9-1646949396f4

the IDE shows no tasks available even though tasks have been added!
new to testing please help me out.

```kotlin
class StatisticsUtilsTest{
    @Test
    fun getActiveAndCompletedStats_noCompleted_returnsHundredZero(){

        // Create an active tasks (the false makes this active)
        val tasks= listOf<Task>(
            Task("title","description", isCompleted = false)
        )
        // Call our function
        val result= getActiveAndCompletedStats(tasks)

        // Check the result
        assertEquals(0f,result.completedTasksPercent)
        assertEquals(100f,result.activeTasksPercent)
    }
```

[reference error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjXn1.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No tasks available when executing JUnit runner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57908805/no-tasks-available-when-executing-junit-runner-class)